# Windows command prompt seemingly ignoring PATH

Tags: windows-7, windows, path, environment-variables

I am trying to use a package called virtualenv for Python, which temporarily changes the PATH environment variable to add a certain directory and give convenient access to several executables. My problem is that this doesn't seem to work. The directory gets added to the start of the path as expected, and I can verify this by typing PATH at the prompt, but if I type the name of an exe in that directory, it doesn't run. If I navigate to that directory however, the app will run ok. It seems like Windows is ignoring the altered environment variable, perhaps using what was listed for PATH in the registry (eg. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path).

Does anybody know what could be causing this? I am running as an administrator on Windows 7.

Comment: Are you trying to execute the application from the same command prompt where you verified the modified PATH, or a different one?

Comment: The same one. Literally in the next command in that window.

Comment: Are you typing the file extension as well? Is the extension listed in `%PATHEXT%`?

Comment: These are .exe files, so the answer is "No" and "Yes" respectively.

Comment: Will Windows launch any other programs from said folder in the path or is it just that file? Something tells me the path was typed in wrong.

Comment: Does the path have spaces in it?  If so, did you remember to put quotes around it?

Comment: It won't launch anything in that directory unless I'm in it. The PATH environment variable is full of spaces (eg. in Program Files) and none of the existing paths in there are quoted - but the other paths in there seem to work fine. These include paths that Microsoft added via their own software, eg. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared.

Comment: Type PATH at the command line to see the current value of the variable, then use copy-and-paste the directory in question from that output into a cd command.  If that works, then you can be certain there isn't a typo.

Comment: You could use process monitor (from Microsoft) to see where cmd.exe is looking for the executables.

Comment: Good idea Harry - however I can't reproduce this today. I wish I'd kept a screenshot of yesterday's session however as I was 100% sure the behaviour was wrong. Will report back if I see it again.

Comment: @Kylotan I had a similar problem for ages. I finally sat down and debugged it using Process Monitor (as suggested here), and I found, I had a typo in the path, causing it to ignore a major part of the %Path% variable. Lesson learned: If Windows ignores your changes to %Path%, you probably have a typo in it! Windows likes to silently ignore errors. Btw, why is this thread closed? It is the first hit on Google when looking for: Windows ignores path. Please re-open it, so I can post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cmd does load the environment variables when it is created, and you have to close it and open a new one to have those refreshed.

There may be a command to force it to refresh the env_vars -

Comment: That doesn't sound right, if you have changed the path from inside cmd, I'm fairly sure it updates right away.

Comment: Well if you change it using the GUI stuff, which makes total sense on a GUI OS, it does not. also people who -1 should think about how that's going to help the poor guys who make the exact same mistake.